# a story about this one javascript function that doesn't work

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

im creating a jsp application , and i got few functions running there. but there is this one function. only one that doesn't work no matter what i do! 
i even built it again now from another running functions and it doesn't work!

here are my functions -

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateAdd(){
    var x=document.add.name.value; 
    var y=document.add.jobId.value;
    var z=document.add.deptId.value;
    var w=document.add.salary.value;
    if(x==""||x==null||y==""||y==null||z==""||z==null||w==""||w==null){
        alert("fields cant be empty"); 
        return false;
    }  
    if(/\D/.test(y)||/\D/.test(z)||/\D/.test(y)){
    alert("job id , dept id and salary need to be numeric!");
    return false;
    }
    }
 function ValidateDelete(){
 var x=document.del.empId.value;
 if(/\D/.test(x)){
 alert("empId needs to be numeric!");
 return false;
 }
 }
  function ValidateGet(){
 var x=document.get.empId.value;
 if(/\D/.test(x)){
 alert("empId needs to be numeric!");
 return false;
 }
 }
 function ValidateUpdate(){
    var x=document.add.name.value; 
    var y=document.add.jobId.value;
    var z=document.add.deptId.value;
    var w=document.add.salary.value;
    var v=document.add.empId.value;
    if(x==""||x==null||y==""||y==null||z==""||z==null||w==""||w==null||v==""||v==null){
        alert("fields cant be empty"); 
        return false;
    }  
    if(/\D/.test(y)||/\D/.test(z)||/\D/.test(y)||/\D/.test(v)){
    alert("employee id ,job id , dept id and salary need to be numeric!");
    return false;
    }
    }
</script>
```

my form is -

```
<form name="update" onsubmit="return ValidateUpdate();" action="GetAndUpdateEmp" method="post" >
update an employee: 
<br> 
empId<input type="text" name="empId"/><br>
name<input type="text" name="name"/><br>
jobId<input type="text" name="jobId"/><br>
deptId<input type="text" name="deptId"/><br>
Salary<input type="text" name="salary"/><br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

another form that works just fine -

```
<form name="get" onsubmit="return ValidateGet();" action="GetAndUpdateEmp" method="get" >
get an employee by id: 
<br> 
empId<input type="text" name="empId"/><br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

im really starting to get crazy i cant find whats wrong

Comment: value can not be null so those null checks are useless. And learn about the [label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: What function doesn't work? What is it about the function that does not work?

Answer (score 2):

The form reference inside ValidateUpdate method does not seem right. You have defined it as "update" but trying to refer to it by "add".

Comment: well , i love you now as much as i hate JS now. thank you... and so sorry i didnt see that till now